# Pyfits reordering axis

Tags: python, numpy, pyfits

I am having a problem, with python, pyfits and numpy. I am opening a fits file with the usual

```
file = pyfits.open('file.fits', memap = True)
```

when calling

```
file.info()
```

It shows me, that the dataset contained has the shape (2,1024,1024,546):

```
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU      12   (2, 1024, 1024, 546)   float32
```

then, I go ahead and import this array into a numpy array via

```
data = file[0].data
```

when I then want to show the shape of this array, using

```
print (data.shape)
```

it shows the shape

```
(546,1024,1024,2)
```

I have no Idea, why it is doing so. It is important to know which dimension belongs to which axis.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#what-convention-does-astropy-use-for-indexing-such-as-of-image-coordinates

FITS axes (as shown in the `.info()`) method, as ordered in the `NAXISn` keywords, are in FORTRAN order.  Numpy, which is based on Python, which in turn is based on C uses C ordered axes.

(As an aside, please be aware that the stand-alone pyfits module is deprecate, and `astropy.io.fits` should be used instead).